# Create a binary search tree with a better complexity

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

You are given a number which is the root of a binary search tree. Then you are given an array of N elements which you have to insert into the binary search tree. The time complexity is N^2 if the array is in the sorted order. I need to get the same tree structure in a much better complexity (say NlogN). I tried it a lot but wasn't able to solve it. Can somebody help?

Comment: Did you even try searching?  GIVEN "Sorted list to bst" Google produces many results, e.g. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorted-linked-list-to-balanced-bst/

Comment: @Gene the link you gave is to sorted linked list to balanced bst, which is not my question.

Comment: @HansSolo: Do you need to produce the exact same link layout as would be produced by the naive algorithm, or do you just need to produce a valid BST? If you just need to produce a valid BST, algorithms for producing a balanced BST should work fine.

Comment: Build a tree with the elements less than the root and put them on the left, and build a tree with the elements greater than the root and put them on the right. That looks to be O(N) if the array is sorted.

Comment: @PaulHankin everytime you start at the root, so if the array is sorted in ascending or descending order, it will be N^2 right?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that all numbers are distinct (if it's not the case, you can use a pair (number, index) instead).

Let's assume that we want to insert we want to insert an element `X`. If it's the smallest/the largest element so far, its clear where it goes.

Let's `a = max y: y in tree and y < X` and `b = min y: y in tree and y > X`. I claim that:

1. One of them is an ancestor of the other.
2. Either `a` doesn't have the right child or `b` doesn't have the left child.

Proof:

1. Let it not be the case. Let `l = lca(a, b)`. As `a` is in its left subtree and `b` is in it's right subtree, `a < l < b`. Contradiction.
2. Let `a` be an ancestor of `b`. If `b` has a left child `c`. Than `a < c < b`. Contradiction (the other case is handled similarly).

So the solution goes like this:

1. Let's a keep a set of elements that are already in a tree (I mean an efficient set with lower_bound operation like `std::set` in C++ or `TreeSet` in Java).
2. Let's find `a` and `b` as described above upon every insertion (in `O(log N)` time using the set's lower_bound operation). Exactly one of them doesn't have an appropriate child. That's where the new element goes.

The total time complexity is clearly `O(N log N)`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Although I didn't quite get this, I'll work on this over the weekend and get back. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you look up a word in a dictionary, you open the dictionary about halfway and look at the page. That then tells you if the search word is in the first or second half of the dictionary. Repeat, eliminating half the remaining words on each pass, and you soon narrow it down to a single word. 4 billion word dictionaries will take about 32 passes.

A binary search tree uses the same principle. Except as well as looking up, you can also insert. Insertion is O(log N), unless the tree becomes degenerate. 
To prevent the tree going degenerate, you use a system of "red" and "black" nodes (the colours are just conventional), and you don't allow long runs of
either colour. The full explanation is in my book, Basic Algorithms

http://www.lulu.com/spotlight/bgy1mm

An implementation is here

https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/babyxrc/blob/master/src/rbtree.c
https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/babyxrc/blob/master/src/rbtree.h

But you will need some explanation if you want to learn about red black
trees from it.